# Simple .gitlab-ci.yml file for compiling a Go binary

Tags: go, gitlab, continuous-integration

The module name in my `go.mod` file is `gitlab.com/mycorp/mycomp/data/hubpull`

The 3 files `go.mod go.sum main.go` are all in the same outermost folder of my project. I have been using these two commands manually on local to compile:

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o main main.go
zip main.zip main
```

Now I need a gitlab CI file to build a binary based on the above 2 commands. I tried searching but a lot of the examples don't work.

Comment: `go build` works on packages, not on files. Please consult the tutorials in go.dev/doc . This is not a priori a Gitlan problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have already tried it, but this is the best simple build CI file for go.

```
image: golang:alpine

stages:
  - build


go_build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o main main.go
    - zip main.zip main
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - main.zip
```

There are more you could add like lint, test, etc (refer this -> https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2017/11/27/go-tools-and-gitlab-how-to-do-continuous-integration-like-a-boss/)